# Can we interpret a parameter's estimate if some of the other parameters haven't reach their stationary distributions (MCMC convergence)?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence

I tried to estimate parameters values in a simple mechanistic model via MCMC (adaptive Gibbs with jags). I have 27 parameters, but it looks like some of the estimates haven't reach their stationary distributions.
I calculated the potential scale reduction factor to assess convergence but I sometimes have psrf > 1.2 (like 1.35 or 1.42). Can I still interpret some of my parameters values (for which psrf < 1.1 or 1.2) knowing that all my chains might have not converged ?

Thank you in advance !

PHen